# Rest call should return objects and internal fields in same sequence

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm using rest call for some testing. UI testing.
After calling rest call and I want it to return fields in object in same order all the time. What can I do for that?
There was assertEquals("some string which is actually o/p of rest call", actualString); in my test.
But after adding one more field in class I observed that it returned rest o/p differently sometimes. 
So I want to have fixed order of fields in returned json, if I call rest call.

I was thinking of using json conversion and asserting on converted java object. 
Like below:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(badIndicatorsdata7.getData());
  MyClass indicatorDto = gson.fromJson(json , MyClass.class);
```

But I'm getting below exception on this line

```
MyClass indicatorDto = gson.fromJson(json , MyClass.class);

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/ideas/tetris/pacman/services/dateservice/dto/DateParameter;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:109)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:349)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:790)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:757)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:706)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:678)
  at com.google.gson.Gson$fromJson.call(Unknown Source)
```

I want below rest o/p in always same order

```
[
    {
        "happy": true,
        "social": false,
    }
]
```

happy and social should not change their order. Is their a way?

Answer (score 0):

> happy and social should not change their order. Is their a way?

Well, that's just a JSON object. It's rare (IME) that the order should matter - and that doesn't look like it's what actually causes the failure you're seeing.

I would suggest that for *testing* purposes you have some code which, given two JSON objects, puts them into some canonical form - but that your *production* code shouldn't care about the order in which properties occur... that would be pretty brittle.

If you really care about ordering, I would suggest creating a list of key/value pairs instead of just a JSON object. That's *meant* to stay in order.

To fix the problem you're actually seeing, however, it looks like you need to find where the `DateParameter` is meant to come from, and make sure that's in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple JSON java library from Crockford. It will create a JSONArray of JSONObject when you parse your string, and JSONObject has a "similar" method (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java#L1295) that will compare the objects independently of the order in the JSON string.